# Pyautogui screenshot - NameError: name 'Image' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, osx-elcapitan, pyautogui

I'm trying to use `pyautogui`'s screenshot functions with Python 3.6.5 on OSX 10.11.

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> image = pyautogui.screenshot()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 331, in _screenshot_osx
    im = Image.open(tmpFilename)
NameError: name 'Image' is not defined
```

My understanding is that `pyscreeze` is failing to get the name `Image` from `Pillow` for some reason. I tried to update the `pyautogui` (it was up to date), then reinstall the `pyautogui`, which carries all its dependencies including `pyscreeze` and `Pillow` along with it.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208631/python-3-pyautogui-cant-use-screen-shot-functions?rq=1) with the same issue, but the fix that worked there (reinstalling) isn't working for me.

Comment: SOLVED: I solved this by downgrading Pillow from 5.1.0 to 5.0.0 and pyscreeze from 0.1.14 to 0.1.13. Guess something got introduced into one of them that messed up the pyautogui functionality.

Answer (score 8):

do

```
pip install Pillow==0.1.13
```

since Image is module from PIL

Comment: In my case, I need to add exactly this package and then the error disappeared. 
Thanks.

Comment: This no longer works: ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pillow==0.1.13 (from versions: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2,...)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Pillow==0.1.13
```

Comment: downgrade your python and then try this @ https://stackoverflow.com/users/6598627/travasaurus

Answer (score 1):

```
pip3 uninstall pyautogui
pip3 uninstall Pillow
```

then reinstall the modules and restart you editor.